# Safari browser support for offline web apps

Tags: ios, safari, web-app

I've been doing research into what solutions are out there for using iOS Safari browsers in terms of offline capabilities with web apps. Many articles and sources I've come across don't seem to mention much in terms of offline support apart from AppCache which is now deprecated.

**I'm wondering if there are any solutions out there for iOS Safari offline support apart from AppCache?**

Answer (score 1):

iOS Safari doesn't currently support offline browsing for web apps. However, Apple is currently working on improving support for progressive web apps, more importantly Service Workers.

Service Workers power offline functionality, push notifications, background content updating, content caching, and a whole lot more.

Here is a somewhat recent article on Service Workers
http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/08/05/apple-may-integrate-service-workers-into-webkit-support-next-gen-web-apps-in-safari